# Difference Between "conducted by " vs "is conducted by"

Tags: passive-voice

1. An experiment conducted by a scientist
2. An experiment is conducted by a scientist
3. An experiment that is conducted by a scientist

Which one is grammatically correct ?

Comment: Only number 2 is normal usage.

Comment: Do you recognize that only (2) is a complete sentence while the others are noun phrases? Also, "music" is an uncountable noun, so we don't say "a" music.

Comment: Did Mozart ever conduct **an orchestra**?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I heard a reference on the radio yesterday to his directing an orchestra from the keyboard. In answer to the original question, we could call it 'a piano concerto _that was_ originally directed by Mozart from the keyboard'.

Comment: @MikeBrockington I have edited my question .

Comment: @TypeIA I have edited my question . Can you tell me which one is complete sentence ? Why the others are noun phrases ?

Answer (score 2):

> An experiment conducted by a scientist *X* ....
>
> An experiment that is conducted by a scientist *X* ...

These are not complete sentences.  A reader/listener will expect a verb at X, or something that begins a modifier phrase.

It is possible for these to be the answer to a question in conversation or written text in a conversational tone if the question is something like *What is X?*.

> An experiment is conducted by a scientist.

This is a complete sentence and is correct.  The sentence has a subject (*an experiement*) and a verb (*is*) and the verb's required complement (*conducted*).

Comment: Sentence 1 "conducted" is an adjective ? Sentence 2 "conducted" is a verb within an adjectival clause that modify "An experiment" ? So in English a clause can be used as a modifier to modify a noun ?

Comment: @Wffmeow In all three sentences, *conducted* is a verb. However, in the first and third sentence, it's a verb that's part of a phrase—the sentence *itself* doesn't have a verb. *[An experiment conducted by a scientist]* … did what? What about … *[an experiment that is conducted by a scientist]*?